# Where and how do I code the request.unvalidated() method for a field in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

VS2013, MVC, VB, CKEDITOR package

I've read several places that I can request a single field to bypass the validation check for embedded HTML.  I need to do this because I'm using CKEditor to collect the text of a user post.  They all say use something like this:

```
Dim rawComment = Request.Unvalidated().Form("comment")
```

This particular example came from MSDN, although I've seen it on multiple forums.  As dumb as it sounds, I don't quite get this.

Is this line to be used in the 'Get' method that sets up the POST form, or in the 'Post' method after the POST?  Or is it supposed to be in a Code Section in the View?  I assume in the sample above that 'comment' is the name of the field.  I don't understand what 'rawComment' refers to or how I would use it.

Comment: You can add the `[AllowHtml]` attribute to your property ([refer docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx))

Comment: I was aware of that granularity, but wouldn't that allow html across the entire project?  My curiosity is about allowing html at the field level.  Wouldn't field granularity allow me to accept html in one method, but not in another? I may wish to have one set of users able to edit with html coding, but another set not, or perhaps in different parts of the application.

Comment: The AllowHtmlAttribute can only be applied to a property of your model and only affects that property (you may be thinking of the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute). If your wanting different sets of users to be able to allow or not allow html on a property, you would probably need different view models (a custom model binder or filter may also be an alternative)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought not intuitively obvious, I was eventually [guided](http://forums.asp.net/p/2036784/5866064.aspx?p=True&t=635600353622752959) to the specific answer I was looking for, requesting unvalidated input on a field by field basis.

This line of code:

```
Dim rawComment = Request.Unvalidated().Form("comment")
```

...is to be placed in the POST method.  'comment' is the name of the field being POSTed, and rawComment is simply the local variable that receives the unvalidated data.

For those of us a little new to MVC there's a 'gotcha.  The field you wish to receive unvalidated cannot be left in the parameters definition of the method; maybe obvious to old heads, but not everyone.  So, remove the field from the parameters of the method and then use the statement above to capture the unvalidated data.

Then 2 more steps remain:

1. That data must be checked for malicious input using some process, probably against a whitelist seems to be the predominant opinion.
2. That data will have to be manually assigned to the object before executing a .savechanges().  Maybe obvious, but if everything else is in a < Bind > definition it's easy to forget this field would no longer be bound and not captured.